# No login screen appears when starting Windows XP computer

Tags: windows-xp, login, login-screen

I have a problem with a Windows XP computer. When I start the computer, no logon-screen appears, so I can not log in. The computer is added to a Windows Domain.

I just see the background and the mouse pointer. The computer has not freezed and I can move the mouse pointer around. Nothing happens if I press Ctrl+Alt+Delete. The same thing happens if I start the computer in Fail Safe Mode.

How can I fix this so I can login?

Comment: You still have to try the "last known good configuration" option (press F8 a LOT after the BIOS POST and *before* the "Windows XP" screen comes up). Also whether it is a dual-monitor desktop where your one monitor is showing the right, empty half of your desktop, and plug in the correct one --you'll know it if you move the mouse to the left border of the screen and it does not appear to stop.

Comment: @Vlueboy: I tried that alternative now, but I got the same problem: just seeing the background and can move the mouse around.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. Which one, the first one about Last Known good? It isn't effective when the problem is old. How old is it? What happened with my monitor-card check? are you sure you're not seeing what desktop #2 shows rather than desktop #1? it's the only other thing short of a reinstall I can think of.

Comment: @Vlueboy: The computer, only has one monitor. We got this problem last friday.

Comment: on further thought I meant "dual-head" instead of dual-monitor;some PCs have multiple output "heads" so Windows may be trying to display the login screen's half through the other outlet --if you have overlooked it and someone changed display settings on friday. When you move your mouse in straight lines around the screen borders, it must NOT exit into hidden desktop space. That's a sign of the problem I mentioned. Otherwise, keep googling 'missing "domain login screen" ' or try a repair install, lastly

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot from a rescue CD such as Ultimate Boot for Windows? [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)  From there I would recommend running chkdsk /r to see if there is a file system issue.  You can also scan for malware offline.  It may be:  bad disk, malware or a corrupt profile.  Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

Get a second computer and attach the hard disk to it as an external drive. Look whether the file "winlogon.exe" is still there.

Background: Windows Update kindly deleted this useless waste of disk space for me when I ran it a few years ago. Thanks, Windows Update. What would I do without you?

Of course! Do important work. ;-)